# More then 1000 rows at T-Sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

Im doing a project right now and the only way that i found to insert the data that i need was to insert it via T-sql running a new query, it was all running cool since i need to insert 24000 records, is there a way i can do using the same approach ?
**Here is a example about what i need to insert**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Estadoes ON;

INSERT INTO countries ([EstadoId], [EstadoNome], [PaisId]) VALUES

(1, 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 101),
(2, 'Andhra Pradesh', 101),
(3, 'Arunachal Pradesh', 101),
(4, 'Assam', 101),
(5, 'Bihar', 101),
(6, 'Chandigarh', 101),
(7, 'Chhattisgarh', 101),
(8, 'Dadra and Nagar Haveli', 101),
(9, 'Daman and Diu', 101),
(10, 'Delhi', 101),
```

Answer (score 0):

So many possibilities (your way [split data if necessary], select .. union all, Data Import in Management Studio, OpenQuery, Bulk Insert, using application, ...)

I'll show you, Using bulk insert.

Lets say "data.txt" has your data like so:

```
1,Andaman and Nicobar Islands,101
2,Andhra Pradesh,101
3,Arunachal Pradesh,101
...
```

If you can reference your data file form your DB server you can do something like this:

```
--Create a temporary table
select top 0 * into #countriesImport from countries;

BULK INSERT #countriesImport
FROM 'C:\temp\data.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',', ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a')

insert countries (EstadoId, EstadoNome, PaisId)
select EstadoId, EstadoNome, PaisId
FROM #countriesImport A 
  left outer join countries B on A.EstadoId = B.EstadoId
where B.EstadoId is null
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: isnt there a way that i can just insert the records directly in the t-sql and run?

Comment: Actualy there is... but it involves XQuery in SQL Server 2008+, but if you didn't go there before, that might just be to mutch. 
In simple stuff like this I usualy use excel and do a cople of steps. ex:
Add some extra columns in excel
[(][1][,'][Andaman and Nicobar Islands][',][101][),]
Copy the excel to notepad
replace all doble space with space
copy to management studio and run it

Comment: well i can handle inserting 1000 records each times, it dont cost me a lot of time, the thing is that evertyme i add 1000 it replaces the 1000 before can i handle that?

Comment: Repaces? what do you mean? your data gets replaced in the database?

Comment: well for example, i insert 1000 records, the next 1000 replaces the 1000 before, when i insert 1000 records everytime